# Multiple, automatic, different effects on one jQuery Cycle banner

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I want to use jQuery cycle to make a banner with several elements that have different automatically playing effects.

For instance I want the image to fade in and out. And the text on top of the image to scroll from left to right.

I made the following HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div>
        <p>txt</p>
        <img src="images/banner1.jpg" alt="banner1" />          
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>txt2</p>
        <img src="images/banner2.jpg" alt="banner2" />      
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to initiate a second jQuery cycle instance with an after inside the first.
But that doesn't work.

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    after: function(currSlideElement, options) {
        $('.slideshow p').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollHorz'
        });
    }
});
```

I also tried two totally different `.cycle` instances but then I got a `next is undefined` error.

Comment: I know what you're asking, and I don't know the answer, but you do know the link to the multiple effects is http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/multi.html ... but I don't think that addresses your issue, if I understand it correctly.  You want 2 separate cycles, one right after the other, each doing their own thing.  I would say pay close attention to and make sure the jquery.cycle.all.js-1.7.1 loads before anything, so put that higher up on in between your head tags.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! And yes, that's exactly what I want to do. Only on the same DIV. In the example the multi effect is loaded on two different DIV's.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will need to write your own transition. Here is a similar question that I answered that may point you in the right direction:   <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177471/animate-content-of-jquery-cycle-slides/10487067#10487067>

Comment: Yup, I see know that I needed to write something myself in the callback of Cycle.